# Hibernate: table thingsdb.Things doesn't exist

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications

I am trying to retrieve all my `Thing`s from the database using Hibernate, but I get this error:

```
Table 'thingsdb.Things' doesn't exist org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

The table in the database is actually named `things`, not `Things`.

The query I am executing is the following:

```
List<Thing> listofthings = session.createQuery(" from Thing thing").list();
```

And the hibernate xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mythings</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="mythings.Thing" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tried to search for a solution but I didn't find it. I am new to Hibernate so I don't really know what to look for or where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the name of the table, otherwise it tries to build the query with the default name which is the class name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="thing")
public class Thing {
    ...
}
```